# i need to get MINx, MAXx, MINy, MAXy

Tags: java

I need to get MIN x , Max x , MINy , MAX y .....I get wrong value

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] matrix = new double [5][2];
    matrix [0][0] = 1.0;
    matrix [0][1] = 2.5;
    matrix [1][0] = 3;
    matrix [1][1] = 4;
    matrix [2][0] = 5;
    matrix [2][1] = 6;
    matrix [3][0] = 7;
    matrix [3][1] = 8;
    matrix [4][0] = 9;
    matrix [4][1] = 10;
    double minx = matrix[0][0];
    double maxx = matrix[0][0];
    double miny = matrix[0][0];
    double maxy = matrix[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <matrix[0].length; j++) {
            if (minx > matrix[i][0]) {
                minx = matrix[i][0];
            }
            if (maxx < matrix[i][0]) {
                maxx = matrix[i][0];
            }
            if (maxy < matrix[i][0]) {
                maxy = matrix[0][j];
            } 
            if (miny > matrix[i][0]) {
                miny = matrix[0][j];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum Of X " + maxx);
    System.out.println("Minimum Of X " + minx);
    System.out.println("Maximum Of Y " + maxy);
    System.out.println("Minimum Of Y " + miny);
}
```

**OutPut**

1. Maximum Of X 9.0
2. Minimum Of X 1.0
3. Maximum Of Y 2.5   >> wrong value
4. Minimum Of Y 1.0   >> wrong value

Comment: Can you please be more detailed? What were you expecting to get and why?

Comment: I insert into array[][] 10 values and i need to get the minimum value of X and maximum Value of X and minimum value of Y and maximum value of Y
i get correct value for x (min , max ) but the y (min,max ) is wrong it shoud be minY=2.5 and maxX=10

Comment: Please load this up in an IDE debugger and step through the code one line at a time (or set breakpoints appropriately) and examine variable values.  This should allow you to find the problem quickly.  In future please do that before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it too complicated, you could do it with a single `for` loop. All you're changing in each comparison is `i` parameter and to know whether it's `X` or `Y` you only compare the second dimension of the array changing it by `0` for `X` or `1` for `Y`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    if (minx < matrix[i][0]) {
        minx = matrix[i][0];
    }

    if (maxx > matrix[i][0]) {
        maxx = matrix[i][0];
    }

    if (miny < matrix[i][1]) {
        miny = matrix[i][1];
    }

    if (maxy > matrix[i][1]) {
        maxy = matrix[i][1];
    }           
}
```

And you need to initialize your `miny` and `maxy` as follows:

```
double miny = matrix[0][1];
double maxy = matrix[0][1];
```

instead of

```
double miny = matrix[0][0];
double maxy = matrix[0][0];
```

However you could have gotten to this solution by using a debugger as suggested by @JimGarrisson in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661735/i-need-to-get-minx-maxx-miny-maxy#comment57069316_34661735) above.

This correctly outputs:

```
Maximum Of X 1.0
Minimum Of X 9.0
Maximum Of Y 2.5
Minimum Of Y 10.0
```

Next time you should also post your actual output (which you did) **and** your expected output (which you didn't)